# Dependency resolution in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I created a sample to test my understanding of dependency resolutions (particularly their order, if any) on .NET Core.
It did clarify some points, but left me with one unanswered.

Consider the following Worker Service template code:

Foo

```cs
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private readonly IGoo Goo;

    public Foo(IGoo goo)
    {
        Goo = goo;
        Console.WriteLine($"Instance of [{this.GetType().Name}] being created...");
    }
}

public interface IFoo { }
```

Goo

```cs
public class Goo : IGoo
{
    private readonly IWoo Woo;
    public Goo(IWoo woo)
    {
        Woo = woo;
        Console.WriteLine($"Instance of [{this.GetType().Name}] being created...");
    }
}

public interface IGoo { }
```

Woo

```cs
public class Woo : IWoo
{
    IFoo Foo;
    public Woo(IFoo foo)
    {
        Foo = foo;
        Console.WriteLine($"Instance of [{this.GetType().Name}] being created...");
    }
}

public interface IWoo { }
```

Worker Service

```cs
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    //private readonly IFoo Foo;
    private readonly IGoo Goo;
    //private readonly IWoo Woo;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, /*IFoo foo,*/ IGoo goo/*, IWoo woo*/)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        //Foo = foo;
        Goo = goo;
        //Woo = woo;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                services.AddSingleton<IFoo, Foo>();
                services.AddSingleton<IGoo, Goo>();
                services.AddSingleton<IWoo, Woo>();
            });
}
```

At first I wanted to make sure the dependency order declaration inside `ConfigureServices` does not matter.
Running the code above, however, prints `Instance of [Goo] being created...` only.
I would expect to have `Instance of [Woo] being created...` printed as well, given it is a dependency of `Goo`, which is resolved.
I would expect `Woo` to be required resolution as well, and therefore its constructor being invoked. But this happens only for `Goo`, not for `Woo`.

**Why is that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because build in DI does not support property injection so `Woo` does not have anything to resolve:

```cs
public class Woo : IWoo
{
    IFoo Foo;
    public void WooM1(IFoo foo)
    {
        Foo = foo;
        Console.WriteLine($"Instance of [{this.GetType().Name}] being created...");
    }
}
```

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#default-service-container-replacement):

> The built-in service container is designed to serve the needs of the framework and most consumer apps. We recommend using the built-in container unless you need a specific feature that it doesn't support, such as:

> - Property injection
> - ...

If you add the ctor:

```cs
IFoo Foo;

public Woo(IFoo foo)
{
    Foo = foo;
}
```

Then you will get the circular dependency exception as expected:

> Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: TestWorker.Worker': A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'TestWorker.IGoo'.

Comment: Argh... I had Woo mistakenly without a ctor (it had a method implementing the interface in my first sample version, where each interface had a method to implement).

Comment: @Veverke yes, that happens. Note that adding ctor still will not work due to the circular dependency problem (you try can work around with factory approach. i.e. something like `services.AddSingleton<Func<IFoo>>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IFoo>)` or `Lazy` pattern with the same structure and then resolving `Func` in ctor  and invoking it in needed methods).

Comment: Yes, I had the circular dependency in mind also from my previous attempts/plays. Now I see that leaving Woo without any dependency will try to resolve both Goo, then Woo (in that order), which is how I expected it to behave. That's what I wanted to see :/

Comment: Thanks though for clearing my way :-)